# Execute async stored procedure in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, asynchronous, plsql

I would like to use Oracle SQL Developer to execute a stored procedure asynchronously a large number of times.

**Pseudo Code**

```
var pStatus number
var pOraErrCd varchar2
var pOraErrMsg varchar2
for i 1 .. 1000 -- do async
loop 
    exec myproc('test',:pStatus ,:pOraErrCd ,:pOraErrMsg);
end loop;
```

The stored procedure's purpose is to do some inserts. For testing I just want to execute the stored procedure asynchronously a large number of times. I don't care about any return values.

Is there a *"easy"* way to do this?

Comment: Do you want a single session that calls the procedure 1000 times in a session other than your own?  Or do you want N sessions simultaneously executing the procedure 1000/N times each?

Comment: Assuming that you need multiple sessions to execute the procedure asynchronously,  N sessions simultaneously executing the procedure 1000/N times each.

Comment: I want to simulate the stored procedure being called rapidly from an external process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you want to simulate N sessions each calling the procedure 1000/N times, I would probably do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE call_myproc_n_times( p_n IN NUMBER )
AS
  p_status         NUMBER;
  p_ora_error_code VARCHAR2(1000);
  p_ora_error_msg  VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. p_n 
  LOOP
    myproc( 'test', 
            p_status, 
            p_ora_error_code, 
            p_ora_error_msg );
  END LOOP;
END;

DECLARE
  l_num_sessions     number := 10;
  l_exec_per_session number := 100;
  l_jobno            pls_integer;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_num_sessions
  LOOP
    dbms_job.submit( 
      l_jobno,
      'BEGIN ' ||
      '  call_myproc_n_times( ' || l_exec_per_session || ' ); ' ||
      'END;',
      sysdate + interval '1' minute );
  END LOOP;
  commit;
END;
```

This example will start 10 sessions each of which will execute the procedure 100 times in quick succession assuming your database's `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` is at least 10 meaning that Oracle is allowed to have 10 jobs running in the background simultaneously.  Creating the `CALL_MYPROC_N_TIMES` procedure isn't strictly necessary-- it just makes building the string to execute in the job easier.

An alternative would be to submit 1000 jobs each of which just called `MYPROC` once and relying on the `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` parameter to limit the number of jobs that would be run simultaneously.  That would work, it's just more difficult to change database parameters if you want to run more of fewer simultaneous sessions-- it's easy to adjust `L_NUM_SESSIONS` in the code I posted.

Comment: very nice, i will be trying it out shortly. I'll let you know how it worked. In the meantime +1

Comment: It seems as though the dbms_job.submit is not working. I created the proc and I can execute it. However, if I try to use dbms_job.submit to execute the job nothing happens. It says the block was completed, but the proc is not getting executed

Comment: @kralco626 - Did you commit?  The job can only run after you've committed the `dbms_job.submit` call.  What is your `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` set to?  If that's set to 0, your database isn't configured to allow background jobs so you need to bump it up.  Do you see the job in `DBA_JOBS` (or `USER_JOBS` or `ALL_JOBS` depending on your privileges)?

Comment: I don't think I have permission to view any of that information. I did execute the `commit` command after the `dbms_job.submit`

Comment: @kralco626 - You should have permission to view `USER_JOBS` at a minimum.  If you don't have permission to view `V$PARAMETER` to see the current `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` setting, you'll need to ask your DBA what the current setting is.

Comment: Yes i can see that. I do see the jobs in there. (I can also see all_jobs, mine are the only ones in there)

Comment: It seems as though the jobs are failing. One of the jobs was scheduled for a minute ago, I refreshed the table and the time was pushed out and the number of failures went from 2 > 3

Comment: @kralco626 - OK, can you post the data from `USER_JOBS`?  The `LAST_DATE`, `LAST_SEC`, `THIS_DATE`, `THIS_SEC`, `NEXT_DATE`, `NEXT_SEC` and `FAILURES` columns in particular.  If you can also let us know what time it is on your server (i.e. SYSDATE including the time component) that would be helpful.  If you don't have access to `V$PARAMETER`, can you ask your DBA what the `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` setting is?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3281/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-kralco626)