# Is it possible to run a select query in background inside sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, select, background

Select query in Oracle is usually handled by foreground process. Is it possible to make the select query run in background (non-blocking run) inside sqlplus?

Comment: In an interactive SQL*Plus command window? Why, and where would the query output go?

Comment: What do you mean by "background(non-blocking run)" ?

Comment: @AlexPoole The intention is to have scan on table without blocking next query.

Comment: But a query implies some output; running two queries simultaneously (if it was possible) would risk the output of both being confused. If you want to run something in the background that doesn't have any output then a job is the way to go; [maybe something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7326283/266304), but using the newer `dbms_scheduler`?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for making it clear. Just to ensure, the intention is not the output but the scan operation on table. Thanks for the link, that looks like a feasible option.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script and execute it via `cron` or `scheduler`, depending on your `OS`. The `SPOOL` will let you have the result of the `select` query in a spool file.

You could also create a `job` using `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.

It has nothing to do with the interactive `SQL*Plus command window`.